# how to get the index or the element itself of an element found with "if element in list"

Tags: python, list, tuples

Does a direct way to do this exists?

```
if element in aList:
   #get the element from the list
```

I'm thinking something like this:

```
aList = [ ([1,2,3],4) , ([5,6,7],8) ]
element = [5,6,7]
if element in aList
     #print the 8
```

Comment: If you have no control over the form of aList, this question is reasonable. If you have created aList and want to access it like a dictionary, why not use a dictionary instead?

Comment: "still new" isn't really an answer.  Does that mean you don't know what dictionaries are or you didn't know they applied to this problem?  Why not use a dictionary?

Comment: I'm already using it, I didn't knew that i could apply it to this problem. I've already implemented it using one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
L = [([1, 2, 3], 4), ([5, 6, 7], 8)]
element = [5, 6, 7]

for a, b in L:
  if a == element:
    print b
    break
else:
  print "not found"
```

But it sounds like you want to use a dictionary:

```
L = [([1, 2, 3], 4), ([5, 6, 7], 8)]
element = [5, 6, 7]

D = dict((tuple(a), b) for a, b in L)
# keys must be hashable: list is not, but tuple is
# or you could just build the dict directly:
#D = {(1,2,3): 4, (5,6,7): 8}

v = D.get(tuple(element))
if v is not None:
  print v
else:
  print "not found"
```

Note that while there are more compact forms using *next* below, I imagined the reality of your code (rather than the contrived example) to be doing something at least slightly more complicated, so that using an block for the *if* and *else* becomes more readable with multiple statements.

Comment: @gnibbler: Thanks for the correction, though I'd rather appreciate a comment that soon after an edit, like within the first 5 mintutes as it was here.

Comment: @Roger, sorry I figured it was just a minor oversight

Comment: @gnibbler: I often go through rapid iterations, as I review how a question reads from multiple perspectives, etc.; in this case I got a warning "this post has been edited by someone else".

Comment: Don't search manually.  Use list.index and catch ValueError.  It's a builtin, so it's much faster, and it's much clearer to use the method eveyone already knows than to roll your own.

Comment: @Glenn: Doesn't apply in this case.  Regardless, the dict solution will be faster than either, and it sounds like a dict is really what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: this answer refers to the question text, not the example given in the code, which doesn't quite match.)

Printing the element itself doesn't make any sense, because you already have it in the test:

```
if element in lst:
    print element
```

If you want the index, there's an index method:

```
if element in lst:
    print lst.index(element)
```

And, on the off chance that you're asking this because you want to loop through a list and do things with both the value and the index, be sure to use the enumerate idiom:

```
for i, val in enumerate(lst):
  print "list index": i
  print "corresponding value": val
```

Comment: The delete link is right above the comments, to the left side (just to the right of the votes).

Comment: @Roger: huh, I see link/edit/flag just above the comments, but no delete. Maybe because I'm not registered? Anyway I decided to restore the answer since someone had already upvoted it, but with a caveat as not quite on point; but thanks.

Comment: It might be because of registration, and I'd rather some answers restored with a note than edit-wiped, just trying to help since you said you couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> aList = [ ([1,2,3],4) , ([5,6,7],8) ]
>>> element = [5,6,7]
```

if you only wish to check if the first element is present

```
>>> any(element==x[0] for x in aList)
True
```

to find the corresponding value

```
>>> next(x[1] for x in aList if element==x[0])
8
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to get the "corresponding value", which is 8 in this case.  (At least it didn't until you edited :P)

Comment: @Roger, that was the answer to the first part of the question

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> aList = [ ([1,2,3],4) , ([5,6,7],8) ]
>>> for i in aList:
...     if [5,6,7] in i:
...          print i[-1]
...
8
```

Answer (score 0):

`[5, 6, 7]` is *not* an item of the `aList` you show, so the `if` will fail, and your question as posed just doesn't pertain.  More generally, the loop implied in such an `if` tosses away the index anyway.  A way to make your code snippet work would be, instead of the `if`, to have something like (Python 2.6 or better -- honk if you need to work on different versions):

```
where = next((x for x in aList if x[0] == element), None)
if where:
  print(x[1])
```

More generally, the expressions in the `next` and in the `print` must depend on the exact "fine grained" structure of `aList` -- in your example, `x[0]` and `x[1]` work just fine, but in a slightly different example you may need different expressions.  There is no "generic" way that totally ignores how your data is actually structured and "magically works anyway"!-)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution.

```
aList = [ ([1,2,3],4) , ([5,6,7],8) ]
element = [5,6,7]

>>> print(*[y for x,y in aList if element == x])
8
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target`

Comment: @Roger Pate:I removed `print` for clarity but it didn't work. Corrected now. Thanks. Any other improvements?? :)

Comment: Just use `[...][0]`; however, the others answers with *next* and an generator are clearer (at least for me), allow for a default value if your list would be empty, and only require iterating *aList* until the first match is found.  Additionally, what you have now is only valid in Python 3.x, but you would print multiple values if present and that's desired.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question is sort of weird. But, assuming you're learning the basics:

#### Getting the index of an element:

it's actually simple: `list.index(element)`. Assuming of course, the element only appears once. If it appears more than once, you can use the extra parameters:

`list.index(element, start_index)`: here it will start searching from `start_index`. There's also:
`list.index(element, start_index, end_index)`: I think it's self explanitory.

#### Getting the index in a for loop

If you're looping on a list and you want to loop on both the index and the element, the pythonic way is to `enumerate` the list:

```
for index, element in enumerate(some_list):
    # here, element is some_list[index]
```

Here, `enumerate` is a function that takes a list and returns a list of tuples. Say your list is `['a', 'b', 'c']`, then `enumerate` would return: `[ (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c') ]`

When you iterate over that, each item is a tuple, and you can unpack that tuple.

tuple unpacking is basically like this:

```
>>> t = (1, 'a')
>>> x, y = t
>>> t
(1, 'a')
>>> x
1
>>> y
'a'
>>>
```

Comment: list.index is not applicable here, as the searched-for item is not directly in the list.